# Optaplanner, what move types does the construction heuristic phase use?

Tags: optaplanner

So I have implemented the TWVRP example with the delay until last pattern: https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.6.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#chainedThroughTimeAutomaticDelayUntilLast

My code freaks out when two parts of the same stop are assigned to the same vehicle, so I try to avoid that by using a ChangeMove selector filter. That filter works just fine, but I still end up in scenarios where visits are assigned this way, and I get score corruption. What other move types does the default CH phase use that I need to filter? Configuration of my CH phase right now:

```
<constructionHeuristic>
    <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
    <changeMoveSelector>
        <filterClass>org.acme.solver.filters.VisitChangeMoveFilter</filterClass>
    </changeMoveSelector>
 </constructionHeuristic>
```

UPDATE:

The score corruption seems to happen during a noop move, (Visit are my stops, Employee are my anchors). Why would Optaplanner try such a move?

```
    VariableListener corruption after completedAction 
(Visit{id=3743c419-aff3-46c6-969c-4c85cb5656ad,
       arrivalTime=2021-06-03T17:00, 
       linkedVisit =76ba82ef-e146-498a-9fdd-8c51adb2198e,
       previousStop=Employee{id=8d2b8894-a13a-41d6-9def-05b2ac1facf2}} 

{Employee{id=8d2b8894-a13a-41d6-9def-05b2ac1facf2} -> Employee{id=8d2b8894-a13a-41d6-9def-05b2ac1facf2}})
```

Comment: VariableListener corruption is usually a bug in your custom variable listener. Do you use one? Please share. Otherwise there is no enough info in the question. I think CH only uses change moves. That is expected. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the filter. Normally, if a move does something you "don't like" you punish that with score. If a change move leads to a corrupted score, you have a problem elsewhere.